# What is the difference between grep root/etc/passwd and getent passwd root

Tags: linux

(Linux DCOM 142 on lab11) (https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWtFs.jpg)

Comment: _Please_ add a proper question to the body of the text, and [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). (I don't have the best eyesight and the photo is of poor quality).

Comment: Furthermore, photos are impossible to read in the occasions I am in the/for users using the mobile application

Comment: Ironically, the answers at the duplicate question and here do not address what the college coursework is getting at.

Answer (score 1):

`getent` will check for data in `/etc/passwd` and other name services. These services can be (e.g.) LDAP, DNS, etc. When passing the `passwd` option, it will get data from the passwd database.

`/etc/passwd` will contain only local users for the current system : it could be considered here as the passwd database.

Apparently you are a studying, so you can read further the manpages of `getent`, `nsswitch.conf`.